# mySQL Case When multiple WHEN-Columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got a table with 13 columns.

id,

jobtitle,keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,
jobtitle2,keyword12,keyword22,keyword23,
jobtitle3,keyword13,keyword23,keyword33.

I am trying to achieve the following.
When jobtitle got a specific value (e.g. Programmer) i want the values of keyword1,keyword2 and keyword3.

When jobtitle2 got a specific value (e.g. Programmer) i want the vaules of keyword12, keyword22 and keyword23.

When jobtitle3 got a specific value (e.g. Programmer) i want the values of keyword13, keyword23 and keyword33.

All three, two or just one jobtitle can have a value.

i got the following mySQL query

```
    SELECT distinct CASE
          WHEN jobtitle = "Programmer" THEN keyword1
          WHEN jobtitle = "Programmer" THEN keyword2
          WHEN jobtitle = "Programmer" THEN keyword3

       END as col_1,
       CASE
          WHEN jobtitle2 = "Programmer" THEN keyword12
          WHEN jobtitle2 = "Programmer" THEN keyword22
          WHEN jobtitle2 = "Programmer" THEN keyword32

       END as col_2,
       CASE
          WHEN jobtitle3 = "Programmer" THEN keyword13
          WHEN jobtitle3 = "Programmer" THEN keyword23
          WHEN jobtitle3 = "Programmer" THEN keyword33

       END as col_3

  FROM tbl_keywords
```

As far as i know somth. like case when jobtitle="Programmer" then keyword1,keyword2,keyword3 is not allowed because only one return value is accepted.

I am just asking myself if my work arround, see my query above is any close to "best-practice" ? If no how would you solve this.

The query is actually working.

Comment: Do you want to select the keywords `keyword1,keyword2,keyword3` into three columns not in one column? right? because in your query you will get only three columns `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3` and only the first condition will be executed then only one keyword will be selected.

Comment: I'll describe my question further by editing.

Comment: You need to do one per output column. However it sounds like your table design is pretty poor. With a properly normalised table design it would be easy to do this using joins.

Comment: It sounds like you are early in on your database, and this smells like a really bad table structure design.  You might want to reconsider what you have and get a better structure first... if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not make any sense - when you repeat the same condition three times you can also do it in one condition. And it looks a lot like a bad table design in the first place to me. You could be better off with splitting the data into different tables or rows but we would need to see the whole Table to get a better idea of how to help you.

Maybe you can do whatever you actually want to do by using nested mysql IF() functions, but as i said i dont think the query is your main problem.

```
SELECT distinct IF(jobtitle = "Programmer",keyword1,IF(jobtitle2 = "Programmer",keyword12, ... ))
```

Comment: Well you are right the table design is poor in that caste.
I'll split the Columns into three Tables its work to change the table design but it will be worth it later i guess.

You may bold your part with the poor table design. I mark that as answer